# convex optimization (problem)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let us have the following task:
$$\min f(x)$$
$$g_{i}(x)\le 0,\quad\forall i$$
$$h_{j}(x)= 0,\quad\forall j$$

What is the correct form of rewriting as a maximize problem?
$$\max - f(x)$$
$$g_{i}(x)\le 0,\quad\forall i$$
$$h_{j}(x)= 0,\quad\forall j$$

or $$-\max - f(x)$$
$$g_{i}(x)\le 0,\quad\forall i$$
$$h_{j}(x)= 0,\quad\forall j$$
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\max f(x) = - \min - f(x)$$

If you have a black box algorithm that knows how to find minima, to find maximum:

1. Multiply the objective by $-1$.
2. Plug the modified problem into the black box
3. Multiply the resulting objective value by $-1$, to reverse the first step. No need to adjust the $x$ of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a convex function, you can write the maximization problem as:

$$ max -f(x) $$

Comment: What? I do not understand none of you. You made it even more complicated for me.  I have no clue about black box algorithm I am thinking about lagrange multipliers.

Comment: didn't mentioned black box algorithm. But it refers to for example a search algorithm that finds the minimum ( for example the root of the derivative of $f(x)$). When your function $f(x)$ is a convex function, you can maximize $-f(x)$ to find the same optimum. You can do this with Lagrange multipliers if you want. Just start with this expression. The algorithm to solve is chosen indifferent from the expression.

Comment: Ok, I changed my question if you have a look. So according to your answer the correct form for maximize is the second one in my question with $\max- f(x)$?

Comment: yes, indeed....

Comment: strange...when you say $\max f(x)=-\min - f(x)$ why is not like this in the optimization task.

Comment: I think you are mixing up the two answers that are given

Comment: Yes, I do not understand why I cannot do it like this. This holds $\max f(x)=-\min -f(x)$ and if I have an optimalization problem with $\min f(x)$ why I cannot rewrite it as $-\max - f(x)$?

Comment: But that's again another question. Take a look at: https://econweb.ucsd.edu/~jsobel/172aw02/notes5.pdf

Comment: Better to remember as a fact for me :-). Anyway, if the task with $\min f(x)$ has a solution, for example $x=a$ what we can say about the solution of the second task $\max - f(x)$. I guess in this case $x$ is not $a$, only the optimalization value of the objective functions in both task as the same. is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117062/discussion-between-steven01123581321-and-dena).